# Creating an if/else Statement so Page Changes Based on Cursor Value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, onclick, qtextcursor

I'm creating a gardening game for kids. The user clicks on the gardening tool (e.g. shovel) they need and then they click on the background image of the field which will take them to the next step/page (e.g. background image of plowed field). The javascript function that changes the cursor to the image of the tool works fine. However, I notice the background image changes on any click which is not what I want. It should only change when the cursor has the right value (i.e. shovel).

To resolve this problem, I thought it might be best to use a second function in the form of an if/else statement.

```
<script>
 function myFunction() {

  document.body.style.cursor = "url(img/Shovel.png), pointer";

}

function changePage() {
  var cursor = document.body.style.cursor;

  if (cursor === "url(img/Shovel.png)") {
    window.location.href = "Potato1.html";
  } else {
    window.location.href = "Potato0.html";
  }
}
```

It's not working as I thought it would, the page automatically changes to the next one. I'm wondering if my logic makes sense so I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: very strange it would be based on the cursor....

Comment: Why on earth would you do that? Why change the page location based on the cursor ??

Comment: You should store picked item in some kinda variable and add onlcick event to image. In event you check if variable == "shovel" or what ever and based on that you procede or not

Comment: I would suggest just changing the background instead. You can have the background associate a behavior with a certain cursor if you want.

Comment: Here's how I saw it: 

There are a range of gardening tools and the kid needs to find the right one. When they click on the shovel, they get a validation message and the cursor changes to that image. They click on the background image (soil) where they would like to plant their seeds and this changes the page. 

Initially, I just had an onclick event for the background image which works fine. However, I realized someone could be clicking on the background image without having picked a tool. So my reasoning was that I should tie the change of page to the cursor to avoid this situation.

Comment: Just look at the second part of my answer, it seems that your `cursor` value is `"url(img/Shovel.png), pointer"` which is indeed different from `"url(img/Shovel.png)"`

Answer (score 0):

The following will display the position of the latest hovered box whenever you click:

```js
var current = undefined;

document.body.addEventListener('click', fn, true);

$('#topLeft').hover(function(){
  current = 'topLeft'
})
$('#topRight').hover(function(){
  current = 'topRight'
})
$('#bottomLeft').hover(function(){
  current = 'bottomLeft'
})
$('#bottomRight').hover(function(){
  current = 'bottomRight'
})

function fn(){
  console.log(current)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:100px; height:100px;">
  <input id="topLeft" style="width:30px; height: 30px; background-color:green;" />
  <input id="topRight" style="width:30px; height: 30px; background-color:red;" />
  <input id="bottomLeft" style="width:30px; height: 30px; background-color:yellow;" />
  <input id="bottomRight" style="width:30px; height: 30px; background-color:blue;" />
</div>
```

For your specific problem, just set the variable whenever somebody click on a tool:

```
$('#shovel').click(function(){
    current = 'shovel'
})
```

then check the variable when you click on the soil

```
$('#soil').click(function(){
    if(current === 'shovel')
        [whatever]
    else
        [whatever 2]
})
```

---

Note:

You are setting the cursor as `"url(img/Shovel.png), pointer"` and then comparing it with `"url(img/Shovel.png)"`. Did you try to debug the value of `cursor` at this point?

```js
document.body.style.cursor = "url(\"img/Shovel.png\"), pointer";

console.log(document.body.style.cursor) // url("img/Shovel.png"), pointer

var result = (document.body.style.cursor === "url(\"img/Shovel.png\")")

console.log(result) // false

result = (document.body.style.cursor === "pointer")

console.log(result) // false

result = (document.body.style.cursor === "url(\"img/Shovel.png\"), pointer")

console.log(result) // true
```

Comment: It also returns false on my end. I understand they are different as you've pointed out above but I'm not sure I understand how this is rendering the value false. The first line for me means either change the cursor to the image shovel or to the pointer if it's not possible. If the cursor has been changed, then var result should be true, no?

Comment: @user9192911 nope, the value in `cursor` **will be** `"url(img/Shovel.png), pointer"`, it is the **rendering** that will either be the `Shovel.png` image or the `pointer`

Comment: Thank you for explaining, the nuance is very subtle. I thought it was understood as two possible values and not one. I also ran the other edits and they also return false. 

I will look at the solution you suggested above, put it in JS because I don't use jQuery and try that. Thanks.

Comment: @user9192911 are you sure the very last one returns `false`? It returns `true` for me

Comment: I repeated the excercise again and it returns false three times...did it in the code snippet as well and it also return false.

Comment: @user9192911 What browser do you use?

Comment: I use Firefox. I just tried it in Chrome and I get the same results.

Comment: @user9192911 Ok, try again with escaped `"` around `img/Shovel.png`, seems like Firefox (and maybe Chrome) adds them automatically. (just run my edited snippet to check)